# Expresso custom payment module

Tags: expresso-store

I have just finished rewriting a custom payment module for Barclaycard ePDQ, and it's working up to a point.

The problem comes on the return from ePDQ, whereby the user is returned to the checkout_confirm page instead of the /store/order/ORDER_HASH as expected.

I just have a pretty standard purchase_return function with

```
return new Merchant_response(Merchant_response::COMPLETE,'',$orderid);
```

The gateway is being sent $this -> param('return_url'); as you'd expect, and if I trap the return I get www.mydomain.mysite/?ACT=16H=  etc etc as expected

Any pointers as to why I'm not getting sent to my order page?

Answer (score 2):

Having found the answer, I realise my question doesn't contain nearly enough details!

I was using POST to retrieve the return parameters, whereas the merchant gateway was sending GET.